# How to decrease the delay to drag and drop files into windows via Dock?

Tags: macos, dock

The Dock (as of 10.7+) allows you to drag files over an application icon, invoking application exposé which allows you to drag the file over the window of choice and drop it in where you want.

The delays set for these actions are rather long for me.
I already checked the Secrets prefpane, no luck.

Is there a hidden preference to speed them up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Finder's preferences, there is an option at the bottom of the General pane for “Spring-loaded folders and windows” that seems to control this. You can adjust the delay using the slider there, and also (as it notes) press the spacebar when dragging an item to invoke Exposé immediately.

It's not a *hidden* preference (in the sense that you need `defaults` to get at it) so much as a preference in a somewhat unexpected place. ;)

Comment: I just did what i hate people doing on Ask Different: posting a stupid question that could have easily be solved by one quick visit to preferences… >_< Although, in my defence, I didn't even think of looking at this, since this option was originally only for folders

Comment: Heehee, I wouldn't have thought to look there myself if I hadn't already known that preference was with Finder's…Apple should really move it to Mission Cntrol or Dock preferences, though.

Comment: Where are the "Finder preferences" ?? [EDIT] Found it (still can't get used to the application menu being separate from its window) Focus on finder - then top menu -> Finder -> Preferences.. You'll find the slider on the General tab.